# How to make Container View stay in background of Parent view content. Swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uicontainerview

In my Storyboard I have a container view that shows over my Parent VC.

The problem is that it covers all the content of Parent view and hides it. The content of Parent Vc Is only visible when i scroll the container VC up.

I want to make the container view stay in background of the content of Parent View.

Comment: If you need help debuging a problem it would be best to add a [mre] to your question.

Comment: @burnsi sorry but i am doing all of this in storyboard and I can't post pictures right now